Next.js 13.5.6 -> "npm run build"-command not type checking .tsx files in pages-folder if file name starts with lower case letter
I am in the process of migrating an existing Next.js project (Version 13.5.6) to TypeScript. I added a simple test.tsx file in the pages directory with two basic type errors:
const Test = (props) => {
  let num = "1";

  num = 2;

  return <div>Test</div>;
};

export default Test;

The type errors are highlighted as expected in red in VS Code but I am still able to do successfull production build via npm run build
However, If if I change the file name to Test.tsx with an upper case letter at the start, the production build fails (as expected).
I only have this upper/lowercase issue in the pages folder, not anywhere else in my project.
What is causing it and how can I solve it?
Ideally I would like to have type checking during the build process, irrespective of the file name's casing.

I figured it out: I deleted and then recreated the test.tsx file with the same name and same content and suddenly the npm run build-process started to pick up the file and aborted the build process due to the type error.
Unfortunately, I still don't know what exactly was the reason for this, but at least I can share the way I fixed it, if someone runs into the same problem.
